I can't open app after installing it Android
I'm working on my first Android app for work time tracking.
MainActivity.java:
package com.example;
import com.example.work.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView startTimeTextView, endTimeTextView, todayTimeTextView, weekTimeTextView;
    private Button startWorkButton, endWorkButton, resetWeekButton, showHelpButton;
    private boolean working = false;
    private long startTime = 0, endTime = 0;
    private float[] workTimes = new float[7];  // Array to store weekly work times

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startTimeTextView = findViewById(R.id.startTimeTextView);
        endTimeTextView = findViewById(R.id.endTimeTextView);
        todayTimeTextView = findViewById(R.id.todayTimeTextView);
        weekTimeTextView = findViewById(R.id.weekTimeTextView);
        startWorkButton = findViewById(R.id.startWorkButton);
        endWorkButton = findViewById(R.id.endWorkButton);
        resetWeekButton = findViewById(R.id.resetWeekButton);
        showHelpButton = findViewById(R.id.showHelpButton);

        startWorkButton.setOnClickListener(view -> startWork());
        endWorkButton.setOnClickListener(view -> endWork());
        resetWeekButton.setOnClickListener(view -> resetWeek());
        showHelpButton.setOnClickListener(view -> showHelp());

        loadWorkTimes();  // Load work times from storage

        updateUI();  // Update UI with loaded data
    }

    private void startWork() {
        if (working) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  // Record start time in milliseconds
            startTimeTextView.setText("Start Time: " + formatTime(startTime));
        } else {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  // Begin initial work session
            startTimeTextView.setText("Start Time: " + formatTime(startTime));
            endTime = 0;  // Reset end time on new session
            endTimeTextView.setText("End Time: ");
        }
        working = true;  // Set working status to true
        saveWorkingStatus();  // Save working status
        updateUI();
    }

    private void endWork() {
        if (!working) {
            endTimeTextView.setText("You haven't started working yet!");
            return;
        }
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  // Record end time in milliseconds
        float workDuration = (endTime - startTime) / 3600000.0f;  // Convert milliseconds to hours
        int dayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek();
        workTimes[dayOfWeek] += workDuration;  // Add work duration to the respective day
        saveWorkTimes();  // Save updated work times
        updateUI();
        working = false;  // Reset working status
        saveWorkingStatus();  // Save working status
        endTimeTextView.setText("End Time: " + formatTime(endTime));
    }

    private void resetWeek() {
        for (int i = 0; i < workTimes.length; i++) {
            workTimes[i] = 0;  // Reset work times to zero
        }
        saveWorkTimes();  // Save reset work times
        updateUI();
    }

    private void showHelp() {
        // Show help dialog or message
        new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Help")
                .setMessage("All commands:\n- Start Work: Start working session.\n- End Work: End working session.\n- Reset Week: Reset weekly work times.")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .show();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        StringBuilder weekText = new StringBuilder();
        weekText.append("Today: ").append(String.format(Locale.US, "%.3fh", workTimes[getDayOfWeek()])).append("\n");
        float weekTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            weekText.append("Day ").append(i).append(": ").append(String.format(Locale.US, "%.3fh", workTimes[i])).append("\n");
            weekTotal += workTimes[i];
        }
        weekText.append("Week: ").append(String.format(Locale.US, "%.3fh", weekTotal)).append("\n");
        weekTimeTextView.setText(weekText.toString());

        if (startTime > 0) {
            startTimeTextView.setText("Start Time: " + formatTime(startTime));
        }
        if (endTime > 0) {
            endTimeTextView.setText("End Time: " + formatTime(endTime));
        }
    }

    private String formatTime(long timeInMillis) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US);
        return sdf.format(new Date(timeInMillis));
    }

    private int getDayOfWeek() {
        return (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) % 7);  // Calculate day of week from milliseconds
    }

    private void saveWorkTimes() {
        getSharedPreferences("workTimesPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("workTimes", serializeWorkTimes()).apply();
    }

    private String serializeWorkTimes() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (float time : workTimes) {
            sb.append(time).append(",");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void loadWorkTimes() {
        String workTimesString = getSharedPreferences("workTimesPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("workTimes", "0,0,0,0,0,0,0");
        String[] workTimesArray = workTimesString.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < workTimesArray.length; i++) {
            workTimes[i] = Float.parseFloat(workTimesArray[i]);
        }
    }

    private void saveWorkingStatus() {
        getSharedPreferences("workingPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("working", working).apply();
    }
}

activity_main.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Work Time Tracker"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startTimeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Time: "
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endTimeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="End Time: "
        android:layout_below="@+id/startTimeTextView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/todayTimeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Today: 0.000h"
        android:layout_below="@+id/endTimeTextView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weekTimeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Week: 0.000h"
        android:layout_below="@+id/todayTimeTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startWorkButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Work"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weekTimeTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/endWorkButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="End Work"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startWorkButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetWeekButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset Week"
        android:layout_below="@+id/endWorkButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showHelpButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Help"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resetWeekButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Work"
        tools:targetApi="31" />

</manifest>

I don't get any errors and I am able to successfully build apk file. However when I install it on my Android device I don't see option to open it. App is installed correctly and I can even find it inside settings->apps...
Folder structure
app/java/com.example/work/MainActivity.java
app/res/layout/activity_main.xml
app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml
Could you please help me to fix this? I have never made an app with Android Studio, so everything is new to me? I would be very thankful.

You are missing the <activity> element that tells Android about your activity and that you want it to appear in the launcher.
Revise your manifest to be:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Work"
        tools:targetApi="31">


        <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
</manifest>


The following is an excerpt from an older book of mine, Elements of Android Jetpack:

The children of <application> mostly represent the "table of contents" for
the app.
Android has four major types of "components":

Activities, representing the UI

Services, representing background processing that is decoupled from the UI

Content providers, which expose databases or data streams to other apps or
the operating system

Broadcast receivers, which supply the "subscriber" side of a publish/subscribe
messaging system used by apps and the operating system to communicate


Most of these will be registered in the manifest via corresponding child elements
of <application>:



Component
Element




Activity
<activity>


Service
<service>


Content Provider
<provider>


Broadcast Receiver
<receiver>



Your app may have several of one type, such as having several activities. Your
app may have none of a particular type, such as having no broadcast receivers
registered in the manifest.
...
<activity> elements have an android:name attribute. This will identify
the Java or Kotlin class that contains the implementation of the activity.
The android:name attribute, in this case, has a bare Java class name prefixed with
a single dot
(.MainActivity). Sometimes, you will see android:name with a fully-qualified
class name (e.g., com.commonsware.helloworld.MainActivity). Sometimes,
you will see just a bare Java class name (e.g., MainActivity).
Both MainActivity and .MainActivity refer to a Java class that will be in your
project's package -- the one you declared in the package attribute
of the <manifest> element.
Sometimes, an <activity> element will have an
<intent-filter> child element describing under what conditions this activity
will be displayed. Most apps will have at least one <activity> element that sets up your activity to
appear in the launcher, so users can choose to run it. That is what this
<intent-filter> element does, though the details of how that works are beyond
the scope of this particular book. Suffice it to say that whenever you see
an <activity> element with this particular <intent-filter> (an <action> of
android.intent.action.MAIN and a <category> of android.intent.category.LAUNCHER),
you know that this activity should appear in the launcher for the user to be
able to start.

thank you very much, I have installed it and I tried to open but it says "Work has stopped" so apps now stops when I try to open it, I get error Unresolved class 'MainActivity' inside AndroidManifest.xml, do you know how to fix this?

the issue was with package com.example in MainActivity.java and I changed it to package com.example.work and now works, thank you very much, this solved problem
